# Quisiera saber como puedo crear una pagina totalmente en blanco en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy intentando crear una pagina totalmente en blanco pero al crearla se me crea con un tema que tengo
es el único tema que tengo así que no lo puedo borrar WordPress versión : 5.7.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo. justamente usas wordpress para que aplique un theme (que es obligatorio) a todo lo que metes adentro.. que es lo que queres hacer?

Comment: @gbianchi quiero crear una pagina en blanco que no tenga un theme

Comment: Exactamente que quieres hacer, porque quieres hacer una pagina en blanco, en wordpress no es posible crear una pagina sin tener un theme activo, en todo caso lo que puedes es crear una plantilla de pagina personalizada dentro del tema actual, preferiblemente en un child theme

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/blank-slate/#description